# Numpy np.interp in tensorlflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, interpolation

I'm looking for function for linear interpolation in tensorflow similar to np.interp(..)
I'm aware that tensorflow is able to receive any numpy function and apply it on tensors but
np.interp is only activated on single object and as far as I checked couldn't be broadcasted.
so is there any efficient way to apply it using tensoflow ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but google brought me here, so my answer might be useful for others.

You can use the [interp_regular_1d_grid](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/interp_regular_1d_grid) from tensorflow probability.
It works in a similar fashion as numpy.interp(), but consult the documentation for exact functionality.